# Using DI to cache a query for application lifetime

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, singleton, ioc-container, ninject

Using a DI container (in this case, `Ninject`) is it possible - - or rather, *wise* to cache a frequently used object for the entire application lifetime (or at least until it is refreshed)?

To cite example, say I have a `Template`. There are many `Template` objects, but each user **will** inherit at least the lowest level one. This is immutable and will never change without updating everything that connects to it (so it will only change on administration demand, never based on user input). It seems foolish to keep querying the database over and over for information I know is not changed.

Would caching this be best done in my IoC container, or should I outsource it to something else?

I already store `ISessionFactory` (`nHibernate`) as a Singleton. But that's a little bit different because it doesn't include a query to the database, just the back-end to open and close `ISession` objects to it.

So basically I would do something like this..

```
static class Immutable
{
 [Inject]
 public IRepository<Template> TemplateRepository { get; set; }

 public static ITemplate Template { get; set; }

 public void Initialize()
 {
  if(Immutable.Template == null)
  {
   Immutable.Template = TemplateRepository.Retrieve(1); // obviously better logic here.
  }
}

class TemplateModule : Module
{
 public void Load()
 {
   Bind<ITemplate>().ToMethod(() => Immutable.Initialize())InSingletonScope();
 }
}
```

Is this a poor approach? And if so, can anyone recommend a more intelligent one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd generally avoid using `static`ness and null-checking from your code - create normal classes without singleton wiring by default and layer that aspect on top via the container. Ditto, remove reliance on property injection - ctor injection is always better unless you have no choice

i.e.:

```
class TemplateManager
{
 readonly IRepository<Template> _templateRepository;

 public TemplateManager(IRepository<Template> templateRepository)
 {
     _templateRepository = templateRepository;
 }

 public ITemplate LoadRoot()
 {
  return _templateRepository.Retrieve(1); // obviously better logic here.
 }
}

class TemplateModule : Module
{
 public void Load()
 {
   Bind<ITemplate>().ToMethod(() => kernel.Get<TemplateManager>().LoadRoot()).InSingletonScope();
 }
}
```

And then I'd question whether TemplateManager should become a ninject provider or be inlined.

As for the actual question... The big question is, how and when do you want to control clearing the cache to force reloading if you decided that the caching should be at session level, not app level due to authorization influences on the template tree? In general, I'd say that should be the Concern of an actual class rather than bound into your DI wiring or hardwired into whether a class is a static class or is a Singleton (as in the design pattern, not the ninject Scope).

My tendency would be to have a TemplateManager class with no static methods, and make that a singleton class in the container. However, to get the root template, consumers should get the TemplateManager injected (via ctor injection) but then say _templateManager.GetRootTemplate() to get the template.

That way, you can:

1. not have a reliance on fancy ninject providers and/or tie yourself to your container
2. have no singleton cruft or static methods
3. have simple caching logic in the `TemplateManager`
4. vary the Scoping of the manager without changing all the client code
5. have it clear that getting the template may or may not be a simple get operation

i.e, I'd manage it like so:

```
class TemplateManager
{
 readonly IRepository<Template> _templateRepository;

 public TemplateManager(IRepository<Template> templateRepository)
 {
     _templateRepository = templateRepository;
 }

 ITemplate _cachedRootTemplate;    
 ITemplate FetchRootTemplate()
 { 
     if(_cachedRootTemplate==null)
           _cachedRootTemplate = LoadRootTemplate();
     return _cachedRootTemplate;
 }

 ITemplate LoadRoot()
 {
  return _templateRepository.Retrieve(1); // obviously better logic here.
 }
}
```

register it like so:

```
class TemplateModule : Module
{
 public void Load()
 {
   Bind<TemplateManager>().ToSelf().InSingletonScope();
 }
}
```

and then consume it like so:

```
class TemplateConsumer
{
 readonly TemplateManager _templateManager;

 public TemplateConsumer(TemplateManager templateManager)
 {
     _templateManager = templateManager;
 }

 void DoStuff()
 {
      var rootTempalte = _templateManager.FetchRootTemplate();
```

Wild speculation: I'd also consider not having a separate IRepository being resolvable in the container (and 
presumably having all sorts of ties into units of work). Instead, I'd have the TemplateRepository be a longer-lived thing not coupled to an ORM layer and Unit Of Work. IOW having a repository and a Manager none of which do anything well defined on their own isnt a good sign - the repository should not just be a Table Data Gateway - it should be able to be the place that an Aggregate Root such as Templates gets cached and collated together. But I'd have to know lots more about your code base before slinging out stuff like that without context!

Comment: So you are saying to create a container that gets the manager, but the manager is independant of the container, so that the manager can be disposed of when the `ISession` is done, but the container('`Consumer`') can retain the retrieved singleton?

Comment: @Stacey: I guess I am. In summary, I'm essentially restating SRP - try tease apart as many responsibilities such as lifetime (singleton), caching, managing traversal of hierarchical relationships and data access into separate concepts - each thing should have only 1 main reason to change. All this has to be kept within reason - it doesnt mean that every single thing needs to become a baby class every time - you just need to be on the lookout for opportunities to simplify matters by doing so.

Comment: A Container (I only use that term as a generalized term for a DI tool) can easily become a golden hammer that can address aspects of all these needs, potentially at the same time, but letting it do so means a) you end up with hairy DI config which is hard to understand because of all these overlapping aims/responsibilities b) you're not aggressively driving important concepts in your code into abstractions such as functions and classes.

Comment: In short yes, I'm saying that if you have a class that does the caching and is lifetime agnostic, you can layer a lifetime/scope on top **and change it easily** without having to refactor the world if it turns out that you want to do something like have a way to dump cached data when its dirty. A final point about caching is that in general, you shouldnt be doing it until a measurement/a profiler has told you that you need it (even if it seems like an open and shut case in this instance).